# Drop last cell in a table to a new row with flex-basis active

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to get a unique table cell to drop to a new row take up 100% width. The project is using flex in the table so I have tried other methods with no success, such as colspan.

Edit: I have an angular directive in the `<tr>`, so this makes it difficult to just add a new `<tr>`

I was hoping someone could help me out with this. A simple structure of the project looks like so:

```
    <tr *ngIf="exampleFunction">
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td class="special">data</td>
    </tr>
```

The fiddle link is below.

https://jsfiddle.net/o4Luzbju/

Comment: Do you have to use flex or are other CSS options possible?

Comment: Unfortunately the code base is using flex. This is why I am kind of a bind on this.

Comment: why not use <br> tags in your td container to break to a new line?..also would you like to break to a new row or a new line?..take a look at your title and the information in your question ....new line or new row?....

Comment: Thanks for that catch @repzero i updated the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Display the table rows as multiline flex containers. Use `flex` to make the cells distribute the space equally, but force a `100%` width to the special cell.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}
tr {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
td {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
.special {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>header</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td class="special">special data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td class="special">special data</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This looks like it should work in my case. Thank you for your effort. I won't touch the code until Monday but I will try to implement your method.

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense to use a table to do what you want. If you want that cell to be a new row on its own, then it should be inside its own `<tr></tr>`.

Use `div` instead of tables, which is much better adapted to your situation.

Comment: to add context, there is an angular directive living in the <tr>, so going out of this would put the new tr out of scope

Comment: The issue still remains that you are trying to achieve something that cannot be done using a table. A cell cannot specify whether it will be on the same row or not as other cells. A table row contains a single line of cells, that's the very definition of a table row. Like I said, you should use divs instead here.

Answer (score 0):

A table cell is a child of its parent row container.. To do something like that, what you can do is  hide the border of that last cell in table and place nothing in that cell..then create a new row

example

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}
td {
  flex: 100%;
  flex-basis: 200px;
  min-width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
.special {
  text-align: center;
}
#null {
  border: none
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>header</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td id='null'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="special">Special data</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Why do you need the null cell?

Comment: I use an id named 'null' (was conducting some experiment)..In fact I remember I place that there to apply a css rule of border none, to hide that border so that It looks like a row break

Answer (score 0):

You can set the table row (`<tr>`) to be the flex container, with option to wrap items onto a new row.

Then set the `td.special`'s initial width to be 100%.

```
table {
  width: 100%;
}

tr {
  display: flex;   /* Initiate flexbox on the container */
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* Let flex items wrap to new line */
}

td {
  flex: 1 0 auto;  /* Flex item to grow to available width */
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

td.special {
  flex: 1 0 100%;  /* Flex item's initial width to be 100% */
}
```